# AngularJS - Unwanted IE8 redirects

Tags: angularjs, internet-explorer-8, click

Using AngularJS, this:

```
<a ng-click="Click()" ng-href="#">Click me</a>
```

Does a redirect to /# in IE8. As does this:

```
<a ng-click="Click()" href="#">Click me</a>
```

And this:

```
<a ng-click="Click()">Click me</a>
```

That last one goes to /. I'm following all of the guidelines for making IE happy:

```
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
  <script src="js/3rd party/html5.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
<!--[if lte IE 8]>
  <script>
    document.createElement('ng-include');
    document.createElement('ng-pluralize');
    document.createElement('ng-view');
    document.createElement('ng:include');
    document.createElement('ng:pluralize');
    document.createElement('ng:view');
  </script>
<![endif]-->
<!--[if lt IE 8]>
  <script src="js/3rd party/json2.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
```

Including using this:

```
<div ng-view></div>
```

It doesn't happen in IE7 or any of the good browsers. Only IE8.

All I want it to do is call my scope's Click function, without doing any redirects. How can I make that happen in IE8?

Comment: try adding `return false;` at end of `Click()` function

Comment: Doesn't help, still getting the redirect.

Comment: what's in `Click()`? One other approach is use `$event.preventDefault()` in `Click()` function and add modify html to: `Click($event)` but `return false` should have done same thing and I think `ng-click` is supposed to prevent default already

Comment: Just this: $("#spinnerdiv").spin(); A simple spin.js jQuery call. Removing it has no effect on the behavior either, either.

Comment: Try using `href="javascript:"` instead of `href="#"` it helped us with supporting older versions of Firefox and might work for you. See [this thread](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/angular/rASA8HQKQF0/m2jgvtZxV3IJ) for some info.

Comment: That seems to have worked. Thank you! Submit it as an answer and I'll mark it as correct.

Comment: `Gloopy`'s comment above should be posted as the correct answer

Answer (score 3):

`button` doesn't work properly in IE8.

Comment: This was a problem i faced, albeit brief, your answer pointed me to the root of my problem.  Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Turn off the html5Mode

```
$locationProvider.html5Mode(false);
```

This will solve the problem, but my question is why?

---

A better solution is to use button instead of a

```
<button ng-click="Click()" class="link">Click me</button>
```

You can change the style of the button with your css

```
button.link { border:none; background: none;}
button.link:hover {text-decoration:underline}
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old post, but `return false;` doesn't work in ng-click handler.

I found I had to set the event.result to false, this way jQuery consumes the event after angular has done it's bit

```
$scope.Click = function ($event) {                

            // needed for IE8 - jQuery will preventDefault action for href=#                
            if ($event != undefined) {
                $event.result = false;
            }
        }
```

Click me

This is particularly helpful if you're using bootstrap, where you have a dropdown menu .e.g

```
<button type="button" class="btn dropdown-toggle btn-primary" ng-disabled="disabled">
    Actions <span class="caret"></span>
</button>
<ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
    <li><a href="#" ng-click="Click1($event)">Option 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" ng-click="Click2($event)">Option 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" ng-click="Click3($event)">Option 3</a></li>        
</ul>
```